# Change port from ipv6 address to ipv4 address

Tags: port, ipv6, telnet, ipv4

I have setup a service on my server which has opened a port (ie, 40000) but its foreign address is :::* which is a wildcard ipv6 address (I think)

When I run telnet localhost 40000 on the server the connection is working fine, but when I try to telnet from my local machine it doesn't work.

When I telnet from my local machine Im using an ipv4 address.

How can I have the port to listen on an ipv4 address rather than an ipv6 address.

By the way, when I run netstat -anp --tcp --udp to check the open ports this is what I get for the port I'm trying to open

Local Address: :::40000
Foreign Address: :::*
State: LISTEN

Comment: What service are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to configure this depends on the service, but you'll want to configure it to listen on the all-addresses IPv4 address, `0.0.0.0:40000`.